# PySimpleGUI is there the Tkinter's equivalent to .after (), to delay updating a window element?

Tags: pysimplegui

I can't do it with the usual  window.read(timeout=) since I have on the screen a clock with seconds updating. And I need to update the two elements only once in 24 hours. Like it can be done in Tkinter.

```
sunrise.after(24*60*60, sunrise)
sunset.after(24*60*60, sunrise)
```

As, Jason suggested I am updating the script with a stripped down version of it.

```
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import datetime
from datetime import date


sg.theme_background_color('#3d5c5c')

clockFont = ('Fira Code', 18)

br1 = {'font': ('Fira Code', 18,'bold')}


def sunrise_sunset(place="my_location"): # put your's
    from suntime import Sun
    from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
    from datetime import date
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")
    location = geolocator.geocode(place)
    latitude = location.latitude
    longitude = location.longitude
    sun = Sun(latitude, longitude)
    time_zone = date.today()
    sun_rise = sun.get_local_sunrise_time(time_zone)
    sun_dusk = sun.get_local_sunset_time(time_zone)
    return (sun_rise.strftime('%H:%M'), sun_dusk.strftime('%H:%M'))

layout = [
    [
    sg.Text("Sunrise", **br1, key='-SUNRISE-',  size=(13,1), text_color='black',background_color="#00ced1"),
    sg.InputText("", size=(6, 1), **br1, key='-ALBA-', text_color='black',background_color='#00ced1'),
    sg.Text("", key='-CLK-', font=clockFont, size=(13,1), background_color="#65000B"),
    sg.Text("Sunset", key='-SUNSET-', **br1, size=(13,1), text_color='black',background_color="#EEAF61"),
    sg.InputText("", size=(6, 1), **br1, key='-TRAMONTO-',text_color='black', background_color="#EEAF61"),
    ]]

window = sg.Window('Run Scripts', layout, finalize=True)

def update_sunrise_sunset():
    if  datetime.datetime.now().hour > 9: # test for 4 am failed, as well as for 7,8,9
        sunrise, sunset = sunrise_sunset()
        window['-ALBA-'].update(sunrise)
        window['-TRAMONTO-'].update(sunset)
        window.TKroot.after(1*60*60, update_sunrise_sunset)


update_sunrise_sunset()

while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=100) 

    try:
        match event:
            case sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
                currentTime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                window['-CLK-'].update(currentTime)

    except Exception as e:
        with open('Run_Scripts_ERRORS_LOG', "a") as f:
            f.write(e)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:  # if the X button clicked, just exit
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of the timeout is meant to be a heartbeat for your application.  If you're updating a timer then you've got quite a bit of accuracy you can use.

This example uses an overkill timeout value of 300ms to demonstrate the decoupling of the timer from the timeout. The application can't rely on the timeout keeping an accurate time as it will drift over time.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import datetime

perform_event1_at, performed_event1_on_day = (7,17), 0

layout = [[sg.Text('Time: '), sg.Text(key='-TIME-')],
          [sg.Text(key='-EVENT1-')],
          [sg.Exit()]]

window = sg.Window('Clock', layout, font='_ 15')

while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=300)
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    # Update the on-screen time
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_string = f'{date:%I}:{date:%M}:{date:%S}'
    window['-TIME-'].update(time_string)

    # Perform event if time to do so...
    if date.hour >= perform_event1_at[0] and date.minute >= perform_event1_at[1] and date.day != performed_event1_on_day:
        window['-EVENT1-'].update(f'Performed event 1 on {date:%m}//{date:%d} at {date:%I}:{date:%M}')
        performed_event1_on_day = date.day
window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Another option that would be particularly good if your application was not already using a timeout would be to use a thread to do your timing.  At the appropriate time, have the thread write an event to the mainthread.  You could also do this with the example above instead of doing the check in the event loop.  Start a thread that sleeps for 12 hours then send the event through with `write_event_value`. The reason I'm suggesting these routes is to no be tkinter specific and also avoid any user code running as a tkinter callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `window.TKroot.after` do the samething.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

width, height = size = 480, 480

layout = [
    [sg.Graph(size, (0, 0), size, background_color='blue', key='GRAPH')],
    [sg.Slider(range=(1, 20), default_value=4, orientation='h', expand_x=True, enable_events=True, key='SLIDER')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
graph:sg.Graph = window['GRAPH']
d, step, figure = 0, 4, None

def rotate():
    global d, figure, step
    if figure:
        graph.delete_figure(figure)
    points = [(d, height-1), (width-1, height-1-d), (width-1-d, 0), (0, d)]
    figure = graph.draw_polygon(points, fill_color='green')
    d = (d+step) % width
    window.TKroot.after(20, rotate)

rotate()

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == 'SLIDER':
        step = values[event]

window.close()
```

#### Update

In following code, function `update_sunrise_sunset` will be executed only once `if datetime.datetime.now().hour <= 9`

```py
def update_sunrise_sunset():
    if  datetime.datetime.now().hour > 9: # test for 4 am failed, as well as for 7,8,9
        sunrise, sunset = sunrise_sunset()
        window['-ALBA-'].update(sunrise)
        window['-TRAMONTO-'].update(sunset)
        window.TKroot.after(1*60*60, update_sunrise_sunset)

update_sunrise_sunset()
```

Maybe it should be like this one, then it will be executed after 1 minutes later again and again.

```py
def update_sunrise_sunset():
    if  datetime.datetime.now().hour > 9: # test for 4 am failed, as well as for 7,8,9
        sunrise, sunset = sunrise_sunset()
        window['-ALBA-'].update(sunrise)
        window['-TRAMONTO-'].update(sunset)
    window.TKroot.after(1*60*60, update_sunrise_sunset)

update_sunrise_sunset()
```

Comment: The sunset, sunrise values update only if I restart the editor, but non automatically, I am missing something. There are no errors. This is how my lines run. window = sg.Window('Run Scripts', layout, finalize=True, default_button_element_size=(16, 2),
    grab_anywhere=True)

def update_sunrise_sunset():
    if  datetime.now().hour > 4:
        sunrise, sunset = sunrise_sunset()
        window['-ALBA-'].update(sunrise)
        window['-TRAMONTO-'].update(sunset)
        window.TKroot.after(3*60*60, update_sunrise_sunset)

update_sunrise_sunset()

while True:

Comment: if possible, update your short and complete code in this post to show how you do it and tell us what the expectation.

Comment: Ok,I did update my post.

Comment: I forgot the sunrise_sunset() function. Now it is in. Sorry,...

Comment: Updated as above.